# AngularJS ui.route on mobile devices

Tags: javascript, .htaccess, angularjs, mobile, routes

I'm building a AngularJS mobile application and I have a strange behavior:

Let's say I have the domain.com/section/:type/:venue

- :type and :venue are parameters that are passed to a service that fetches some information for me.

**The problem:** whenever I access the link DIRECTLY (domain.com/section/:type/:venue) on a desktop browser, the page loads, the requests are made etc. **BUT** on a mobile device I get a 404 not found error, I always have to start from the root to be able to get there.

I am really curious what is causing is, and more importantly how can be fixed or a workaround this issue. (I was thinking of somehow redirecting the user to root, saving the parameters and then redirecting to that link, maybe using .htaccess, but I don't know if that is a viable or even a possible solution.)

I'm guessing that on the desktop browser, there's also a request made to the root of the domain to get some info and then the template and Angular is loaded, but I can't seem to search for proper queries to find more information on this.

Comment: Try this on your mobile domain.com/#/section/:type/:venue

Comment: I just put `<base href="/">` and some htaccess rules to get rid of the #, it's dirty to have # everywhere, is there no other way?

Comment: Are you using html5mode?

Comment: Yes, combined with base href and htaccess rules to have nice links, and I am testing in Safari on iOS and Chrome/iOS.